# Why does Tumblr default image sizes to a maximum of 500px?

Tags: css, image, tumblr

When I upload an image to Tumblr the maximum size is 500px. Why is this?

Is there an easy way to change the maximum size without hardcoding every post or loading them externally?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your the theme that you're using, I believe.

Tumblr does allow you to upload high quality images, it's just that Tumblr's templating engine does not have tags for image sizes higher than 500, except for loading an image full resolution. There's a high res category in the Tumblr themes gallery which should help.

Comment: I believe there is a next-higher res other than full resolution. Of course since that resolution seems to be 1280, it's not much different from full-resolution in most cases.